# Jquery Window Scroll Active specific item

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax.js

Please check my coding ! i want to activate only one item which one will be coming from bottom. but when i running this  code it's activating all div .

$(window).scroll(function() {
$('.parallax').each(function(e) {
if($(window).scrollTop()<=120){
$(this).addClass('active');
}
}); 
});

<div id="home" class="parallax" style="height:600px; width:400%; display:block; border:1px solid #F00;">
  </div>
  <div id="features" class="parallax" style="height:600px; display:block; border:1px solid #F00;">
  </div>
  <div id="newsletter" class="parallax" style="height:600px; display:block; border:1px solid #F00;">
</div>

Answer (score 0):

If you look at following codes:

```
 $('.parallax').each(function(e) {

   if($(window).scrollTop()<=120){
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }

}
```

which actually mean if the window top is lower than 120, then all *'.parallax'* will be set to style *active*.